# A click on a bell icon notification in Communities (now called Digital Experiences) doesn't navigate

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, notification

Having [managed to get notifications to appear by not including a "state"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331750/bell-icon-in-communities-syntax-of-the-settargetpageref-string) and so using:

```
Map<String, Object> pageRef = new Map<String, Object>{
    'type' => 'comm__namedPage',
    'attributes' => new Map<String, Object>{
        'name' => 'cvcp__event-details'
    }
};
notification.setTargetPageRef(JSON.serialize(pageRef));
```

a click on a notification item generates a browser error (in Chrome) of e.g.:

> Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
> 'nonce-GzsQXTm1bMh16s0QBEqIhyq4Vrp152Im'
> https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/ import: blob:". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

The Salesforce Platform generated link is:

```
<a class="notification-link" href="javascript:void(0)" ...>
    ...
</a>
```

So this is probably [an irrelevant error](https://www.google.com/search?q=void%280%29%20csp&oq=void%280%29%20csp)?

There is a successful POST request made to:

> https://.../portal/s/sfsites/aura?r=14&ui-notifications-components-notifications-controller.Notifications.markNotificationRead=1

at the same time but that looks like just an update that the notification has been read.

One related post is [lightning:navigation not passing the States in URL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257611/lightningnavigation-not-passing-the-states-in-url).

Does anyone understand what part here makes the navigation occur and what I can try to make the navigation work?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the "comm__namedPage" approach shown in the question with names of:

- cvcp__event-details
- c__event-details
- event-details

and none of those worked.

What did work, and with the benefit of being able to inject query parameters (that I would have preferred to use "state" for but the API does not allow that) was:

```
Map<String, Object> pageRef = new Map<String, Object>{
    'type' => 'standard__webPage',
    'attributes' => new Map<String, Object> {
        'url' => '/portal/s/event-details?eventId=a0756000005VLI3AAO'
    }
};
notification.setTargetPageRef(JSON.serialize(pageRef));
```

So I will be using his approach for now. (The CSP console log error shown in the question is still output but the navigation works.)

Comment: for us this worked `Map<String, Object> pageRef = new Map<String, Object>{
'type' => 'comm__namedPage',
'attributes' => new Map<String, Object>{
'pageName' => 'home'
}};` for navigating to home

Comment: Thanks @NagendraSingh; good to know it works fine for a standard page name. Do you have any examples of custom page names?

Comment: It does work for with Page api name, for redirecting it to required page, but as you said there is no way to include query params in that.

Comment: Thanks @NagendraSingh.